# iOS Swift version of Adobe Creative SDK

Tags: swift, aviary, adobecreativesdk

How to invoke image editor of Adobe CreativeSDK from iOS swift

i have gone until this step.

https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/02/using-the-creative-sdk-from-a-swift-app/

Answer (score 2):

There is no Swift implementation of the SDK itself, but you can still use it with your Swift codebase.

A very simplified overview of how to set it up is:

1. Set the -ObjC flag
2. Use the Split Framework pre-processor macro
3. Specify framework search paths in the build setting
4. Link with the Creative SDK Binaries
5. Copy Resources (compiled storyboards and images used in the SDK UI components)
6. Provide a bridging header

There are details on how to do all of these things on [the Creative SDK blog](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/02/using-the-creative-sdk-from-a-swift-app/).

Comment: Thanks for the initial input. i have gone thru your blog.I did all that and now what next.Can you pls provide how to invoke the editor...thanks

Comment: For further specific questions, on Stackoverflow it's better to create a new question instead of commenting on this one. As a quick final note, there are a few resources you might check, including [the Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html) and [the sample apps repo](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/ios-getting-started-samples).